# Is an event horizon absolute to all observers?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, observers, causality, event-horizon

Recently I had discussion whether the [event horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon) of a black hole is absolute or relative to different (outside) observers. Does someone just 1m above the horizon (disregarding effects of tidal forces, stability of orbits etc.) perceive it at the same depth as someone at infinity?

I'm not able to prove it theoretically. My only justification is that the relation "information from point $A$ can reach point $B$" is transitive, so all photons that can reach 1m above the horizon can also reach distant observers.

Comment: Somebody at infinity from a stellar black hole would feel nothing of the event horizon, someone one meter above it would be torn into subatomic pieces. How is that supposed to be "the same"? Photons that start out one meter above the event horizon will be greatly redshifted relative to photons of the same energy that start out at (almost) infinity. Also not the same. Am I missing the hard part of the question?

Comment: You would not necessarily be torn to bits, the tidal force ar the event horizon depends on the size of the black hole. For a large black hole, the tidal force would be very small.

Comment: @Ihle: That's only true for the free falling observer. The stationary observer would feel enormous gravity.

Comment: @CuriousOne I am not talking about the strength of gravity, which is relative (dependent on your reference frame), I am talking about the tidal forces, which are the ones that would rip you apart. But, since you mention it, the strength of gravity that a stationary observer close to the horazon would feel does not have to be very strong, it depends on the mass of the black hole.

Comment: @Ihle: A black hole with a 1g surface gravity would have to have a radius of about one light year (give or take a pi or two).

Comment: @CuriousOne, "radius of about one light year" - what is it compared to infinity mentioned in the question? - almost nothing. If you would have calculated it to be significant % of total mass of the Universe, than it may matter.

Answer (score 10):

The definition of the event horizon is `the boundary of the past of future null infinity', so it is the surface beyond which nothing can escape *to infinity*. It isn't defined with reference to any observer.

A consequence of the definition is that an observer can never really determine where the event horizon is, since its location depends on all future events. In principle, you could be falling through the horizon of a black hole right now and not know it, if some aliens conspire to collapse a big shell of matter on top of you at some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disappoint you. The Schwarzschild Radius is defined as Holographer points out, but with one constraint not mentioned here. And that is the Schwarzschild radius [only applies](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/bh/schwp.html) to an observer with infinite distance to the observed object and at rest. The formula does not apply to any other distances or observers in movement. Thus any realistic observer will not observe the event horizon according to the Schwarzschild radius but instead an observer specific phenomena.

The gravity of the black hole bents not only space but space-time. This applies not only for empty space but for all observers likewise. Depending on their observation position they perceive mutually exclusive realities. This is not only true for black holes but applies in general to any observer in this universe as is explained and agreed upon already since long time by General Relativity.

Have a look at this [research piece](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/insidebh/schw.html) at the University of Colorado into the subject which provides even a video simulation of falling into a black hole. Its really cool!

Answer (score -1):

Good question. I think the event horizon has to be absolute, because as you suggested, light either gets out or it doesn't. I venture to suggest that isn't in accord with what most here would say is current teaching, but here's a couple of interesting facts:

1) Light is not redshifted when it ascends, and nor is it blueshifted when it descends. You can work this out by sending a 511keV photon into a black hole. The black hole mass increases by 511keV/c², not a zillion tonnes. Conservation of energy applies. There is no magical mysterious action-at-distance mechanism wherein a photon in space somehow acquires or loses energy. What happens is that I do work on you when I lift you up. So you have more mass-energy when you're higher, so you might think the ascending photon has lost energy. It isn't unlike SR redshift where you accelerate away from the light source and the photon appears to have lost energy. However the photon didn't change, instead *you did*. It's the other way round when you're lower, see the [mass deficit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy#Mass-energy_relation).

2) Light increases its speed when it ascends vertically. [Like Einstein said](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol7-trans/156?highlightText=%22speed%20of%20light%22), a gravitational field is a place where the speed of light is spatially variable. We say the "coordinate" speed of light varies with gravitational potential, and we note that *optical* clocks go slower when they're lower. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_light_in_non-inertial_reference_frames) and note that *at the event horizon of a black hole the coordinate speed of light is zero*. It's zero for the guy 1m above the horizon, because he doesn't see the light getting out. It's zero for the guy 1000m above the horizon, because he doesn't see the light getting out. It's zero for the guy 1000000m above the horizon, because he doesn't see the light getting out. And so on. Because light doesn't slow down as it ascends, instead it speeds up. See [this](http://www.desy.de/user/projects/Physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/speed_of_light.html) old Baez article and [the new version](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/speed_of_light.html) along with these words by editor Don Koks: *"light speeds up as it ascends from floor to ceiling"*.

Given that there's no errors in the above, I can't see how the event horizon can be relative. If we had a gedanken string of lights dangling into the black hole, IMHO all observers would agree on how many lights are visible, because the light at some location either gets out or it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

The event horizon is not absolute. It all depends on the observer. THAT is relativity. Space/time is relative to the observer. An event horizon is the consequence of space and time curving to a degree that light cannot escape relative to an observer at a certain point in space/time. An observer close enough to the black hole to be affected by its gravitational “force” would observe time differently, therefore the event horizon would be closer to the singularity. The closer to the singularity an observer, the more the event horizon would change from their POV. If able to observe the black hole from the singularity everything would become infinite. The observer would basically witness the end of the universe.

Answer (score -2):

According to the relativistic doppler effect light shifts into blue or red depending on the relative velocity of object and observer. Thus, looking at a redshifted light ray which source is close to the event horizon of a SMBH it must be possible to shift its light back into blue just by accelerating the speed of the observer by the relative amount. Transformed this onto the event horizon itself, where the redshift becomes infinite and thus the light won't escape anymore at that point, just by increasing the speed of the observer must have the ability to "unshift" the light again. Just by looking at this, the question „if“ light escapes a SMBH seems to be observer relative as well.

This further would mean that the radius in which hawking radiation is produced would be a observer-relative effect as well. (refrain from lynching me, I'm just theorizing)

Furthermore by approaching the strong gravitational field the observer would be subject to spacetime curvature as well as the object. Thus it only seems logic if relativistic effects again are perceivable. So, by moving closer to the event horizon, the observer itself being subject to spacetime curvature as well would then see the spacetime curvature at the (from outside seen) event horizon (or object) less curved, as he perceives it relative to his own experienced curvature. (Right ?) Thus it only seems logically that the event horizon will seem like shrinking once approaching it. An event horizon can't be proven absolute or observer independent if these assumptions cannot be disproved.

I appreciate if someone can prove me wrong without making more obvious mistakes than myself. I’m not a physicist, I’m just pondering why I can't find any big criticism to the absolute event horizon theory. The only alternative I have found is the apparent horizon, but its definition only seems to get applied on pertubed black holes and/or spacetime and does not inherit a difference between an apparent horizon and an absolute horizon in a black hole.

Further it is said, that the speed of gravitational waves cannot exceed c. Thus, the event horizon must not be only a barrier to light, but also for gravitation. Thus, how could a mass behind the event horizon be detected outside at all? Could it be that the classic idea of something "behind" the event horizon is misleading in that sense, as that spacetime due to its curvature does not permit any euclidic descriptions behind the event horizon, so that all the mass and energy exactly accumulates at the event horizon, because there "is" no behind ?

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't make any sense. As a general rule, it is dangerous to attempt to use intuitive arguments in general relativity as intuition will usually lead you astray. Questions about GR can only be answered properly by going through the maths, which I'm afraid usually makes it inaccessible to non-physicists.

Comment: Thanks John, for the comment. But as of my information there is not scientifc math behind the event horizon. The only insights I have encountered so far cover the event horizon itself and thus describe 2 dimensional problems. And again, while all this relativity being relative, how can the event horizon be absolute and not observer relative?

Comment: The geometry around a black hole is described by the Schwarzschild metric, and this is unambiguously clear about the location of the event horizon. To write down the metric we need to choose a coordinate system, and the (hyper)surface that constitutes the horizon will be obviously written down differently in different coordinates. But all such descriptions are of the same object, which is invariant to coordinate transforations. The seems to me as good a definition of *absolute* as one is likely to get.

Comment: Thanks guys for making that interesting. On english wiki it is mentioned that an observer approaching the event horizon will never experience to cross it, while it will always appear below him, which confirms my initial theory.

"Observers crossing a black hole event horizon [... will ...] never experience crossing this visual horizon."

from [wiki:EventHorizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon)

Comment: That does not confirm your "theory". That description only means to convey that an infalling observer at or below the event horizon radius will always be able to see light coming from at or above their radius but never from below . The location of the event horizon to any observer outside of it will always be the same. The gravitational time dilation and redshift point to the same location of the event horizon regardless of the observer's location. The math is quite clear

Comment: Furthermore, you are confusing the notion of gravitational waves with that of a gravity field. The gravitational waves are bounded by $c$ and those originating from within the black hole do not escape. However, the gravitational field is established by the mass of the black hole. This mass existed prior to the black hole's formation and had a set gravitational field. Also, all of the infalling matter had a gravitational field prior to crossing the event horizon. Gravity waves transmit updates to the gravity field.....

Comment: The effect of the black hole simply means that the gravitational field outside of it is never updated from when its mass was located immediately next to the event horizon. Effectively, this means that the gravity field around a black hole can be said to be generated by its combined mass if that mass were evenly distributed in a shell the radius of its event horizon. The shell theorem makes this turn out to be equivalent to the gravitational field of a point mass. An infalling observer would again always see the mass shell beneath them, so the BH always would act as a point mass.

Comment: Now, the simplified explanations I gave are merely a way you could think about it. But the truth of the matter is described purely mathematically. The way it actually works is that the mass curves spacetime. The curvature of spacetime is not globally bounded to a velocity when event horizons are involved, just ask the distant objects in the universe that are moving away from us faster than $c$. Descriptions of curved space are often unintuitive, but the math is sound. The event horizon is at a set radius

Comment: Dear Jim, thanks for the explanation about the gravitational waves and field. Sounds sane.

As for the static event horizon being not observer dependent makes no logic sense even after your explanation. When you read the article behind that wiki source (for that certain paragraph I cited here) you will see that its even possible for an observer falling behind the (from far seen)  event horizon to see another absorber who fall into it shortly before him.

Comment: I am wondering if we are all reading the same paragraph ...

"objects [...] entered the horizon along the same radial path but at an earlier time would appear below the observer but still above the visual position of the horizon" [en.wiki/EventHorizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#cite_note-casa.colorado.edu-1)

Comment: You can read everywhere that the schwarzschild metric can only be applied on far observers. Thus it's misleading to take this as justification here. If an observer "behind" the horizon still can see something which entered the horizon before him in time than this is an observer who sees not the same horizon as an far outside observer who only sees both "hanging" on the horizon.

Comment: "The geometry around a black hole is described by the Schwarzschild metric, and this is unambiguously clear about the location of the event horizon. "

This sounds like crazy talk.  Isn't this merely an approximation you get by assuming that the Black Hole is a point?